# How does expansion matter?

Tags: macros, expansion, loops

```
\newcount\@repeat%
\def\repeat#1#2{%
\@repeat#1\relax%
\ifnum#1>\z@\relax%
  \advance\@repeat by -1\relax%
  \repeat{\@repeat}{#2}#2%
\fi}%
\repeat{2}{1}\\%
\repeat{11}{f}\\%
\repeat{\repeat{2}{1}}{f}% this does not work
```

The macro `\repeat#1#2` repeats the argument #2 a total of #1 times.
I expect the last two lines produce the same thing, but the last line is wrong.

Why can't the last line produces the letter f 11 times? Does expandability matter? I don't quite understand it.

How I should edit the code so that they produce the same thing?

Comment: What should the desired output of the last line look like?  I can't discern your intent.  For example, this: `\repeat{2}{\repeat{5}{f}}` does work, producing 10 `f` characters.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: the last line should give eleven letters.

Comment: So that is a "one" digit, and not a lower-case  "ell"?

Comment: No letter 'ell'. Repeating digit one twice gives eleven.

Comment: Please always post complete code. Is this intended to be plain tex? latex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
```

because `\repeat` has

```
 \ifnum#1>\z@
```

so `#1` has to expand to a number, but it is `\repeat{2}{1}` which includes many non expandable constructs such as   `\@repeat`, `\relax` and `\advance`.

Also although unrelated to the error in this fragment, it is a very bad idea to redefine `\repeat` as it is part of the basic `\loop` construct used throughout LaTeX and plain TeX.

This version just uses expansion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter


\def\xrepeat#1#2{%
\ifnum#1>\z@
  \xrepeat{\numexpr#1-1\relax}{#2}#2%
\fi}%
\xrepeat{2}{1}\\%
\xrepeat{11}{f}\\%
\xrepeat{\xrepeat{2}{1}}{f}% this does not work

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought `\repeat{2}{1}` also expands to the number 11. Now it seems it doesn't. Why? What does it actually expand to?

Comment: @HYC In your original `\repeat{2}{1}` expands to `\@repeat2\relax\ifnum....`  where `\@repeat` is a non expandable reference to a count register. `\@repeat2` makes a non-expandable _assignment_ of that register to 2, but assignments always happen after expansion.

Answer (score 3):

David has already explained why the nested `\repeat` command can't work and also why it's a bad idea to use the name `\repeat`.

Here's a different definition, based on `expl3`: I'd say it's way easier, judge for yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \xrepeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\xrepeat{2}{1}\\
\xrepeat{11}{f}\\
\xrepeat{\xrepeat{2}{1}}{f}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Explanation

The `expl3` package suite already provides the function you want to define and it's called `\prg_replicate:nn`. So we just make an alias for it. *C'est tout.*